# Método que añada los elementos de lista de posiciones y que su suma no supere a contador. Java

Tags: java

Necesito resolver que este método añada elementos a una lista y que los elementos que añada, su suma no supere a contador. 
Por ejemplo cuando llamo a este método en el main con lista=[3,3,5,6] añade(lista,3), me devuelve [3] (correcto) pero cuando llamo en el main a este método con lista=[3,3,5,6] añade(lista,4) me devuelve [3,3] y debería devolverme [3]. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo? Gracias. Mi código es el siguiente

```
 public static PositionList<Integer> añade (PositionList<Integer> lista, int contador){
            PositionList<Integer> resultado = new NodePositionList<Integer>();
            if(contador<=0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if(list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
                return resultado;
            }
            Position<Integer> cursor = lista.first();
            Integer suma = 0;
            while(cursor != null && suma < contador) {
                if(cursor.element() <= contador) {
                    res.addLast(cursor.element());
                    suma = suma + cursor.element();
                }
                cursor = lista.next(cursor);
                }
            return resultado;
            }
```

Comment: podrias editar tur pregunta y explicarte mejor en ambos casos envias `list=[3,3,5,6]`

Comment: en ambos casos envío la misma lista, pero con distintos valores a contador

Comment: esa funcion no usa nunca contador... como es que hace algo?

Comment: Ya está corregido, tenía una n en vez de contador.

Answer (score 0):

creo que aqui quisiste decir result en lugar de res:

```
res.addLast(cursor.element());
```

pero bueno,por lo que veo es que terminas el while al momento que tu suma ya superó tu contador,y deberia ser antes que lo sume,  podria quedar como :

```
while(cursor != null && (cursor.element()+suma< contador) ) {
```